# When two or more dependent clauses are used?

Tags: conditionals

I want to explain my problem with the following sentence:

> No one knows if the excited stammerer knew of the earlier word, or simply made a mistake or if the story was just a clever marketing ploy of Lowe's.

We know that, when a clause starts with *if* that this clause acts a dependent clause. But in that example there has two dependent clauses. Is it possible?

Would anybody like to give some examples of this kind of sentences? At the same time, I have failed to realize the meaning of the cited sentence.

Comment: Put back the *"if he"* before *"simply"* that was left out of the sentence. Does that help?

Comment: substitute "if he simply" for "or simply".

Comment: There is no limit to the number of dependent (subordinate) clauses there can be in a sentence. All the sentence needs is comma intonation -- and, in print, a comma to represent it -- after _mistake_. _If_ is retained to flag the last clause, where conjunction reduction has **not** deleted an identical subject -- i.e, _the excited stammerer_ is the subject of the first two disjuncts linked with _or_, though it's deleted in the second one; but the subject of the last clause is a different noun phrase, _the story_.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one dependent clause (which below I've abbreviated DC).  The general rule for conjunction is that the category for the entire conjoined constituent is the same as the categories for each of the constituents that are conjoined.  Here, in construction with "knows", we have a DC, and that DC is of the form: DC or DC.  In bracketed form, it's:

> No one knows [DC [DC if the excited stammerer knew of the earlier word, or simply made a mistake ] or [DC if the story was just a clever marketing ploy of Lowe's ] ].

Although it's not what you're asking about, there is another instance of this within the first of the conjoined (or "disjoined") DCs.  The subject is "the excited stammerer" and the (single) VP is "knew of the earlier word, or simply made a mistake", which VP consists of two VPs connected by "or":

> [VP [VP knew of the earlier word ] or [VP simply made a mistake ] ]

(The comma before the first "or" makes me uneasy.  Perhaps it would be better moved to before the second "or".)